# How to toggle different colors on consecutive clicks (on SVG objects)

Tags: javascript, function, svg, colors

I'm trying to let all elements in group change to specific colors on different amount of clicks. One click = red, two clicks = blue, etc. It needs to toggle all children in the group.

#### JavaScript

```
function call1() {
    console.log('call1');
    const children = document.getElementById('btn1').children;
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("btn1").toggle(
            function(){$("btn1").css({"fill": "red"});},
            function(){$("btn1").css({"fill": "blue"});},
            function(){$("btn1").css({"fill": "green"});
        });
    });
}
```

#### SVG file

```
<g id="btn1" onclick="call1()">
    <polygon fill="#FF0013" points="366.699,131 410,56 453.301,131  "/>
    <polygon fill="#07FF00" points="323.699,656 367,581 410.301,656     "/>
    <polygon fill="#0000FF" points="409.699,656 453,581 496.301,656     "/>
    <polygon points="366.699,581 410,656 453.301,581    "/>
</g>
```

I want all the elements in the SVG group to change colors on the first click to red, second click to green, and third click to blue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a modulus and switch statement to cycle through each colour:

```
var count = 0;

function call1() {
  const button = $("#btn1");
  console.log(count);
  count = count % 3 + 1;
  switch (count) {
    case 1:
      button.css("fill", "red");
      break;
    case 2:
      button.css("fill", "blue");
      break;
    case 3:
      button.css("fill", "green");
      break;
  }
}
```

Example:

```js
var count = 0;

function call1() {
  const children = $("#btn1").children();
  count = count % 3 + 1;
  switch (count) {
    case 1:
      children.css("fill", "red");
      break;
    case 2:
      children.css("fill", "blue");
      break;
    case 3:
      children.css("fill", "green");
      break;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg height="1000" width="100%">
  <g id="btn1" onclick="call1()">
    <polygon fill="#FF0013" points="366.699,131 410,56 453.301,131  "/>
    <polygon fill="#07FF00" points="323.699,656 367,581 410.301,656     "/>
    <polygon fill="#0000FF" points="409.699,656 453,581 496.301,656     "/>
    <polygon points="366.699,581 410,656 453.301,581    "/>
  </g>
</svg>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: this only changes the fill of the elements that don't already have a fill

Comment: Are you sure? Can you point me towards where my code is wrong?

Comment: Hi, Your code seems to not work: I'm still trying to work out an error, I get: "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined", for line 4 on javascript

Comment: @TKoL I think i fixed it

Comment: @Thomas that's jquery

Comment: @Thomas You need to include this line at the below your `<body>` tags: `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
`

Answer (score 1):

I'm putting the colors in an array.
I'm setting a counter. The counter n++ every time you click.
I'm setting the color class for the group

```
n %= colors.length;
btn1.setAttribute("class", colors[n])
```

Please read the comments in my code

```js
//the array of the colors
let colors = ["tomato","gold","skyblue"];
//the attay of the polygons
let polygons = Array.from(svg.querySelectorAll("#btn1 polygon"));


let n = 0;
svg.addEventListener("click",()=>{
  //remove the fill attribute of the polygons
  polygons.forEach(p =>p.removeAttribute("fill"))
  //the color for the group fill
  n %= colors.length;
  //reset the class name for the btn1
  btn1.setAttribute("class", colors[n])
  n++
})
```

```css
svg{border:1px solid;width:100px;overflow:visible}

polygon{stroke:black}


.tomato{fill:tomato}
.gold{fill:gold}
.skyblue{fill:skyblue}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" viewBox="300 50 230 650" >
<g id="btn1" >
    <polygon fill="#FF0013" points="366.699,131 410,56 453.301,131"/>
    <polygon fill="#07FF00" points="323.699,656 367,581 410.301,656     "/>
    <polygon fill="#0000FF" points="409.699,656 453,581 496.301,656     "/>
    <polygon points="366.699,581 410,656 453.301,581"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the svg a bit to make this work, and I used Kobes code as a starting point:

https://jsfiddle.net/gz9mc06r/

In the svg, I changed it from using the 'fill' property to using `'style="fill:..."'`

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 800 800"><g id="btn1" onclick="call1()">
    <polygon style="fill:#FF0013" points="366.699,131 410,56 453.301,131  "/>
    <polygon style="fill:#07FF00" points="323.699,656 367,581 410.301,656     "/>
    <polygon style="fill:#0000FF" points="409.699,656 453,581 496.301,656     "/>
    <polygon points="366.699,581 410,656 453.301,581    "/>
</g>

</svg>
```

Javascript looks like this:

```
var count = 1;
window.call1 = function() {
    const button = $("#btn1 polygon");
  console.log(count);
  count = count % 3 + 1;
  switch (count) {
    case 1:
      button.css("fill", "red");
      break;
    case 2:
      button.css("fill", "blue");
      break;
    case 3:
      button.css("fill", "green");
      break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<svg onclick="changeStyle()" id="Component_358_18" data-name="Component 358 – 18" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <defs>
        <style>
            .cls-1 {
                fill: none;
            }

            .cls-2 {
                fill: rgb(0, 0, 0);
            }
        </style>
    </defs>
    <rect id="Rectangle_1638" data-name="Rectangle 1638" class="cls-1" width="24" height="24" />
    <path id="Union_19" data-name="Union 19" class="cls-2" d="M20235,16695v-3h24v3Zm0-7v-3h24v3Zm0-7v-3h24v3Z"
        transform="translate(-20235 -16674)" />
</svg>






<script>

    var svg = document.getElementsByClassName('cls-2')[0];
    function changeStyle() {
        if (svg.style.fill === 'red') {
            svg.style.fill = 'black';
        } else {
            svg.style.fill = 'red'
        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).